# Search landmarks of a place using latitude and longitude in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, geocoding

I made a Rails app to find the latitude and longitude of a computer from its IP address.
Can i search for the landmarks like Hotels,Cinemas,etc from the latitude and longitude using geocoder? If yes.how?

Comment: you can use google places api for this. what did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to use the geocoder gem but it is not working